# Way to import node modules inside jmeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

Whether node modules can be used inside jmeter?
For example can we import node modules inside webdriver sampler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) is a **server-side** scripting engine, the only "good" way to use it from JMeter is via [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

If you want to use some Node.js module in the browser driven by Selenium you might want to take a look at [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) which is capable of producing a single .js file which you can load and call its functions.

In general the only recommended scripting option in JMeter is using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), I'm pretty sure that your requirement can be implemented in Groovy